# Gstreamer streaming multiple cameras over RTP while saving each stream

Tags: c++, camera, video-streaming, gstreamer, rtp

I am currently working on a project that utilizes a Nvidia Jetson. We need to stream 3 cameras over UDP RTP to a single source (unicast), while saving the contents of all three cameras.

I am having issues with my pipeline, It is probably a simple mistake somewhere that I simply am not seeing.

```
gst-launch-1.0 -e v4l2src device=/dev/video0 ! 'video/x-raw, width=(int)640, height=(int)480' ! tee name=c c. ! queue ! omxvp8enc bitrate=1500000 ! rtpvp8pay ! udpsink bind-port=8574 host=129.21.57.204 port=8574 loop=false c. ! queue ! omxh264enc bitrate=1500000 ! mp4mux ! queue ! filesink location=test-RightFacingCamera.mp4 v4l2src device=/dev/video1 ! 'video/x-raw, width=(int)640, height=(int)480' ! tee name=b b. ! queue ! omxvp8enc bitrate=1500000 ! rtpvp8pay ! udpsink bind-port=8564 host=129.21.57.204 port=8564 loop=false b. ! queue ! omxh264enc bitrate=1500000 ! mp4mux ! queue ! filesink location=test-LeftFacingCamera.mp4 v4l2src device=/dev/video2 ! 'video/x-raw, width=(int)640, height=(int)480' ! tee name=a a. ! queue ! omxvp8enc bitrate=1500000 ! rtpvp8pay ! udpsink bind-port=8554 host=129.21.57.204 port=8554 loop=false a. ! queue ! omxh264enc bitrate=1500000 ! mp4mux ! queue ! filesink location=test-FrontFacingCamera.mp4
```

Now the issue here is that 2 of the 3 streams will simply stop without cause, there is no debug information at all, they will simply cease to stream and write to the file after about 2 minutes of up time.

Additionally, I have considered converting this into C/C++ w/Gstreamer, I would not know where to begin if someone would like to point me in a direction. Currently I have a javascript code written up that detects each camera by serial number and assigns a port to the given camera. Then runs this command.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was caused by the cameras themselves. Turns out that ECON brand cameras have an issue where 3 of the identical camera will not work in v4l2. My team and I have bought new cameras, all identical model to test, and it works fine.

We were using ECONS because of supposed scientific quality and USB-3 speeds. Unfortunately we do not have USB3 speeds or bandwidth, so we are stuck on a lower resolution.

Hope that helps anyone that runs into a simaler problem, the current cameras that seem to all work asynchronously over USB2.0 are Logitech c922s

Answer (score 1):

This is usb **bandwidth limitation of Jetson**. We can support 3 camera at a time with compromising the frame-rate. The Logitech camera is compared and that camera is H.264 camera (It gives compressed frames) so it afford to give 60fps bandwidth.